# NSTask : Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13 when launching app

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, nstask

I have a sub-app in my main Swift app. I made it so it's copied automatically in the Resources folder of the main app when building it. That way, I want to be able to launch an instance of the sub-app from the main app.

The thing is, I'm having an error that is hard to debug/find answers about.

Here is my code :

```
    let args = ["--args", "-admin_url", site.url, "-login", site.login, "-pass", site.password]
    let helperPath = (NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("App Helper", ofType: "app"))!
    let task = NSTask.init()
    task.launchPath = helperPath
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
```

And the error :

```
[56490:7218926] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 13
```

I have no idea where to look, what to search for. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I'm wondering if the issue is related to the sub-app itself. That sub-app is empty for now. I set `Application is Agent` to `YES`. And in MainMenu.xib, I set the `Visible at launch` option to no.
That sub-app needs to do some work in the background and doesn't need any UI at all.

Thanks !

Comment: `Error 13` is an error for `Permission Denied`. What is your `helperPath`? If it is not `/usr/bin`, you will get this error.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NSTask` for this, use `NSWorkspace`:

```
let helperAppURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("App Helper",
                                      withExtension:"app")!

_ = try? NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(helperAppURL,
       options:[.Default],
   configuration:[NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments :
            ["--args", "-admin_url", site.url, "-login",
             site.login, "-pass", site.password]])
```

In the above code, for brevity, I ignored the result of the `openURL()` command, but in reality it can return an instance of `NSRunningApplication` which represents the task.

To keep track of the instances of your helper app you launch, you could keep references to this `NSRunningApplication` in an appropriate kind of collection class, and when the time comes, call its [`terminate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunningApplication/terminate) method.

Comment: This works properly, thank you. But I'm not sure it's compatible with what I need to do. I need to be able to launch several instances of the app helper (this is ok I believe), and terminate a given one programmatically. Task does have a `terminate()` method. Can I do something equivalent with `openURL()` ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do something similar with `openURL(_:options:configuration:)`. Updating answer...

Comment: NSWorkspace has problems with Catalina and above

Comment: https://www.appsloveworld.com/swift/100/65/nsworkspace-openconfiguration-ignores-arguments-despite-not-being-sandboxed

Using process is preferable

Answer (score 2):

the `launch()` function is deprecated, using `run()`

```swift
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
  let task = Process()
  task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/"
  task.arguments = ["-c", command]
  
  let pipe = Pipe()
  task.standardOutput = pipe
  
  if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
    try? task.run()
  } else {
    task.launch()
  }
  
  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
  
  return output
}
```

or using [swift-commands](https://github.com/QiuZhiFei/swift-commands)

```swift
import Commands

Commands.Bash.run("say hello")
```

Comment: Interesting, this fixed the issue for me but I didn't get any deprecation warnings.